# Medieval alternative London with abductions

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I only had the chance to start reading this urban fantasy book and memories are hazy but it was promising… it was set in London, medieval or so definitely pre-modern. There were abductions by a set of really creepy characters I think, some real odd houses, including a woman who looked dead but wasn’t… not much to go on but hopefully someone will remember. It started with a seedy guy kidnapping a girl and dropping her off to a very strange trio of people, I think.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? Right now there’s not much to go on: this could describe a variety of books. Even a distinctive name or word could help. Something as trivial as the gender of the main character(s) could jog someone’s memory.

Comment: [Neverwhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwhere_(novel)) springs to mind.

Comment: It's not Neverwhere. It started with a seedy guy kidnapping a girl and dropping her off to a very strange trio of people. I think.

Comment: Great. Could you add that information to the question? Also, can you remember *how* the trio was strange?

Comment: I edited the quote from your comment into the question. Comments are temporary, so it’s best to have that additional information in the main body of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be [The Oversight](http://www.fantasybookreview.co.uk/Charlie-Fletcher/The-Oversight.html) ?

> The Oversight is set in Victorian London and we are slowly introduced to the people who will guide us through this London where The Oversight protect humanity from the supranatural who would prey on them. The Oversight are people who have mixed blood, part natural and part supranatural, who have sworn to protect the natural from what lurks in the dark. The Oversight at this time consists of Sara Falk, Cook, Mr Sharp, The Smith and Hodge, all who have different powers. Their job is to maintain the balance between the worlds which has been thrown out of balance by the appearance of Lucy Harker, a girl who has large parts of her memory missing. It is Lucy’s journey of discovery that we follow here as she learns that there is more to the world she lives in than she could ever imagine. Is she purposely there to destroy The Oversight? Or are there stranger plans afoot?

The book does start as you suggest.

> It started with a seedy guy kidnapping a girl and dropping her off to a very strange trio of people, I think.

Comment: Wow thanks that's the one!

Comment: Very spookily I'm currently 4/5ths of the way through reading it at the moment !